# Making a variant of existing github project

Tags: github

I've download a github project and made kind of my own variant of it.

It makes heavy use of the original code and shares the same goal,
but it has a very different approach.

So the questions are..

1) Am I eligible to start a new github repository without permission? (code didn't specify anything about permision issue)

2) Is it okay to open a completely new repository, or should I add to the original as a branch?

Comment: The git philosophy is that you should just fork off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fork the repository and commit whatever changes you want. You might even issue a Pull Request to show what you did to the original authors. Maybe the original authors like your changes and include it in their repo

Comment: btw, Can I make the forked versions also publicly available even without pull request?

Comment: As long as you don't make the repo private it's going to be public anyway